# What defines a device as connected to the Internet?

Tags: ip, network

I recently saw a SO question: Are there global networks other than the Internet? I am aware of other networks such as ATM and the telephone network, which are not part of the Internet. My question is, what are the criteria that determine whether a network is part of the Internet or not? Moreover, what determines if a device is connected to the Internet? I am assuming this has to do with the protocol stack that is run.

To give some examples: BitTorrent and the Ethereum blockchain, to my knowledge, are Internet applications. This is because they are built on top of the Internet, and nodes running the BitTorrent or Ethereum protocol still run IP underneath it all. In this sense, BitTorrent and Ethereum are simply *overlay* networks on top of the Internet. But fundamentally, they are still part of the Internet, and the devices running those protocols are still "Internet" devices.

Comment: There really is no strict definition -- you're free to define it yourself.  The Internet is made up of commercial, educational, and government networks.  If your device can communicate with them, then you're connected to the Internet.

Comment: Voting to close as mostly opinion-based.

Comment: Actually, there are *two* Internets - one running IPv4 and one with IPv6. While the infrastructure is mostly identical, that isn't necessarily the case everywhere. A device with *any kind* of connectivity with those networks (full stack, partial stack, mapped through an application-layer protocol over another device, ...) may be considered as "connected" - the exact grade varies widely and would need further definition, making this question opinion-oriented.

Comment: *Overlay network* can be applied to any system you put on top of an existing network. IP often works as an overlay on top of Ethernet (with added functionality, of course). Accordingly, *overlay* can just refer to a higher layer (like in your case), in contrast to a fully featured network stack (like with tunneling, for instance).

Comment: Internet is a network that uses IP protocol at layer 3 (as pointed out by Zac67 there are 2 of them now). This is commonly illustrated by IP hourglass e.g., this one: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Internet-hourglass.svg. From Internet standpoint Etherium and BitTorrent are applications that run on top of Internet. Since these applications are distributed systems with potentially a lot of nodes involved, it might be useful to think of such applications as networks themselves, as in design them using similar layer principles. Thus we have an overlay.

Answer (score 1):

> what are the criteria that determine whether a network is part of the Internet or not?

The internet is a network of networks (or, as pointed out in comments, one network of IPv4 networks and one of IPv6).

A network is "part of the Internet" if it's connected in such a way that it can route packets to and from another network that is "part of the Internet", and that network is willing to forward packets for it.

> I am assuming this has to do with the protocol stack that is run

Well, you need to be running an [Internet Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc791) (whether v4 or [v6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc8200)).

In theory you can have anything you want on top of that, but most applications are built on top of TCP/IP and/or UDP.

There are a collection of other protocols that are either widely-used implementation details (ICMP, BGP) or that provide services people consider logically part of the internet (DNS, HTTP, SMTP).

> BitTorrent and the Ethereum blockchain, to my knowledge, are Internet applications.

They're both application prototocols layered on top of (an) Internet Protocol. You can run them on a private network, or a network of private networks - you'd just need to provide all the resources they require (DNS and some local equivalents for the services it would have found on the internet).

> In this sense, BitTorrent and Ethereum are simply overlay networks on top of the Internet

They're not networks except metaphorically. At least, they're not networks in the same sense as the ones that are linked to create the internet.

Consider the road network, which links my "network" of supermarkets. My customers, and my suppliers, and my competitors' suppliers - all travel over the road network.

I can consider my supermarkets a "network" for logical, logistical, and management purposes, but that doesn't create any more asphalt or allow anyone to drive over it. All the vehicles are still on the same physical roads.

Comment: what do you mean by "TCP/IP and/or UDP". UDP packets are sent over IP as well. Also, i disagree with "There are a collection of other protocols that are either widely-used implementation details (ICMP, BGP) or that provide services people consider logically part of the internet (DNS, HTTP, SMTP)." HTTP is a part of web, not Internet, it is application layer. SMTP is part of email, which is also application layer. And what does "widely-used implementation detail" mean? ICMP is needed for IP for some functionality. BGP is also not exactly optional.

Comment: If the OP doesn't distinguish clearly between application protocols and networks, then the appropriate abstraction level is the same one at which many non-technical people will consider HTTP etc. to be "part of the Internet". BGP is required for peering, but not for point-to-point links, and again I don't think that's the level of detail OP is operating at.

Comment: well, maybe we shall explain the difference between application and network, not promote this wrong-thinking. OP clearly wants a technical answer, or expects it since it is asked here. BGP is required to connect ASes to each other, well actually to find routes to destinations in other ASes. Traffic still uses IP header. These routes are still for IP. At this level of detail it is not worth mentioning BGP at all. It only causes confusion. ( I would also argue that links connecting 2 BGP routers of different ASes are more likely point-to-point than the links connecting hosts to Internet.)